# Add Background Image behind TextView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, uitextview

Hey guys,
Does anyone know how to make the Text View transparent and add a Background Image behind the Text View? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In viewDidLoad

```
textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:textView.frame] autorelease];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myBackgroundImage.png"];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:textView];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to make a new class. (Did not test the code, just typed it on the forum, try to use the code otherwise: use the concept)

```
@interface TextViewWithImage : UIView {
   UITextView *textView;
   UIImageView *imageView;
}

@property (retain, readonly) UITextView *textView;
@property (retain, readonly) UIImageView *imageView;

@implementation TextViewWithImage

- (id) init {
   if (self = [super init]) {
      [self setupContentViews];
   }
   return self;
}

- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
   if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
      [self setupContentViews];
   }
   return self;
}

- (void) setupContentViews {
   textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
   imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

   textView.frame = self.frame;
   imageView.frame = self.frame;

   textView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
   imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
}

- (void) dealloc {
   [textView release];
   [imageView release];
   [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

UIViews (of which UITextView is a subclass) have a property called backgroundColor.

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) UIColor *backgroundColor
```

Try calling [textView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]] on the TextView and putting an image view behind it.